# ElasticSearch Painless script: How to iterate through a nested array object and apply custom logic

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have several documents(each user) and each document has some list of experiences with description and joining, end dates. I am using 6.4.2 version.

I am trying to create a query where:

1. query_string to get the documents of matched keywords.
2. Create the custom field using script_fields where

   1. Loop through each nested array object and search for keywords against the description field.
   2. If matches then get the end date.
   3. If matches multiple descriptions then get the recent end date.

keywords = 'financial data'

```
    query = {
        'query': {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "candidates.workExperiences",
                    "query": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": keywords,
                            "fields": ["candidates.workExperiences.description"],
                            "default_operator": "AND"
                        }
                    },
                    "inner_hits": {
                        "script_fields": {
                            "receny": {
                                "script": {
                                    "lang": "painless",
                                   "source":"doc['candidates.workExperiences.end'].value"
                               }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        },
        "_source": ["candidates.workExperiences", "receny"]
    }
```

Output:

"{'_index': 'index_fb0bdc63-bdb1-48e1sdfds-dfds, '_type': 'profile', '_id': '5b8febee803fd50a94wqeqw', '_score': 16.880539,
'_source': {'candidates': {'workExperiences': [{'id': '59ce03e4aa87df1212qs','start': '2015-06-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'description': 'Analyze large amounts of information to discover trends and patterns in financial domain. ', 'end': '2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z'},
{'id': '59ce03e4aa87df4daewrw','start': '2014-06-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'description': 'Calibration Methods & Tools New Powertrain Services', 'end': '2015-05-01T00:00:00.000Z'},
{'id': '59ce03e43err7df4da0ee4er', 'start': '2012-07-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'description': 'Synthesizing and analyzing financial data (like budgets and income statement forecasts) with consideration for the company’s goals', 'end': '2014-05-01T00:00:00.000Z'}]}},
'inner_hits': {'candidates.workExperiences': {'hits': {'total': 1, 'max_score': 16.880539, 'hits': [{'_index': 'index_fb0bdc63-bdb1-48e1sdfds-dfds', '_type': 'profile', '_id': '5b8febee803fd50a94wqeqw', '_nested': {'field': 'candidates.workExperiences', 'offset': 2}, '_score': 16.880539, 'fields': {'receny': ['2014-05-01T00:00:00.000Z']}}]}}}}"

I want output as below:

"{'_index': 'index_fb0bdc63-bdb1-48e1sdfds-dfds, '_type': 'profile', '_id': '5b8febee803fd50a94wqeqw', '_score': 16.880539,
'_source': {'candidates': {'workExperiences': [{'id': '59ce03e4aa87df1212qs','start': '2015-06-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'description': 'Analyze large amounts of information to discover trends and patterns in financial domain. ', 'end': '2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z'}]}},
'inner_hits': {'candidates.workExperiences': {'hits': {'total': 1, 'max_score': 16.880539, 'hits': [{'_index': 'index_fb0bdc63-bdb1-48e1sdfds-dfds', '_type': 'profile', '_id': '5b8febee803fd50a94wqeqw', '_nested': {'field': 'candidates.workExperiences', 'offset': 2}, '_score': 16.880539, 'fields': {'receny': ['2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z']}}]}}}}"

Comment: Sorry it's not very clear now what you're trying to achieve. Could you please prepare some minimal example without irrelevant fields, ready to copy-paste into curl or Kibana console, and a matching desired output example?

Comment: I am trying to extract users with specific experience (out of all his experience) along with end date by looping through the nested array objects and searching in the description field.